# H.323 PROTOCOL PACKET CAPTURE

Tags: networking, voip, wireshark, rtp, h.323

I would like to study the H.323 protocol in a practical way using wireshark.I know it makes use of H.225 and H.245 protocols for communication purpose. Can somebody help me how to have setup (just as we set ftp server and use ftp client) so that i can get packets capture (using wireshark) belonging to H.323 (H.225 and H.245) protocols. Even if somebody tell me the links to sample pcap files belonging to H.323 (H.225 and H.245) protocol, it will be fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue as you had in the past. Did you have any progress in this project? Did you find any packet format or signature to filter H.225 packets? (Please use @ to mention me)

Answer (score 1):

You could download the free [Ekiga](http://www.ekiga.org) and make a few H.323 calls between 2 Windows PCs and make your own captures.